# Creating table before creating a cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, temp-tables

I have a PL/SQL procedure which creates a temporary table and then extracts the data from this temporary table using cursors, processes the data and then drops the temporary table. However Oracle doesn't allow the usage of cursor if the table doesn't exist in the database.

Please help me handle this.

Comment: Why do you create and then drop the temporary tables instead of creating them once, and using them over and over again? -- If you are coming from a SQL Server background, Oracle is different. Temporary tables are permanent objects that hold temporary data.

Answer (score 8):

Your statement is not quite correct. You can use a cursor for pretty much arbitrary queries. See below:

```
create or replace procedure fooproc
IS
    type acursor is ref cursor;
    mycur  acursor;
    mydate date;
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'create global temporary table footmp (bar date) on commit delete rows';
    execute immediate 'insert into footmp values (SYSDATE)';
    open mycur for 'select * from footmp';
    loop
        fetch mycur into mydate;
        exit when mycur%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(mydate);
    end loop;
    close mycur;
    execute immediate 'drop table footmp';
END fooproc;
/
```

(More details [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:6618793099164641::::P11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054) - especially this short proc is not safe at all since the table name is fixed and not session-dependent).

It is (quite) a bit ugly, and I'm not suggesting you use that - rather, you should be thinking whether you need that procedure-specific temporary table at all.

See [this other article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1164655862293):

> DO NOT dynamically create them [temp tables], DO NOT dynamically create them, please -- do NOT dynamically create them.

Couldn't you use a global temporary table? Do you actually need a temporary table at all? (i.e. doesn't using a cursor on the select statement you'd use to fill that table work?)

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you wish to avoid differences between global temporary tables and "regular" permanent tables you may be used to (see [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CNCPT1138) on temp table data availability, lifetime etc), simply create the table first (nologging).  Assuming nobody else is using this table, your procedure could truncate before/after your processing.